# State data missing in react-route-dom-v6 when moving to the next screen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I pass array data from one screen to another using `react-router-dom`. The issue I am having is sometimes; the data is not being sent in its entirety.

Sending the data.

```
navigate("/CustomerInformation", { state: {petData: petDataArray }});
```

I consoled out the petDataArray before sending it and got two object

```
[
   {
      "petObj":{
         "name":"Jaxon",
         "breed":"Akita",
         "comments":"Test",
         "birthday":"20210811",
         "gender":"Female",
         "breeding":"Fully Functional"
      }
   },
   {
      "petObj":{
         "name":"Bo Champ",
         "breed":"Akita",
         "comments":"This is a test edit",
         "birthday":"20210820",
         "gender":"Female",
         "breeding":"Spayed"
      }
   }
]
```

When I go to the next screen and console out the `location.state` inside `useEffect()`, some of the data in one object is missing.

```
[
   {
      "petObj":{
         "name":"Jaxon",
         "breed":"Akita",
         "comments":"Test",
         "birthday":"20210811",
         "gender":"Female",
         "breeding":"Fully Functional"
      }
   },
   {
      "petObj":{
         "name":"",
         "breed":"",
         "comments":"This is a test edit",
         "birthday":"",
         "gender":"",
         "breeding":"Spayed"
      }
   }
]
```

[Codesandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/dazzling-shirley-voo7tx?file=/src/AppCustomerSearch.js)

Comment: This may be one of those instances where a *running* [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/) demo that reproduces the issue that we could inspect and debug live?

Comment: I've added the sandbox code but the issue is not happening

Comment: Your code snippet here and sandbox may be *too* minimal then if they are exhibiting different behavior. What is different between the sandbox code and your *actual* code? I'm currently suspecting an object mutation somewhere, but need to see a more complete and comprehensive [mcve] to verify/validate/confirm.

Comment: @DrewReese, thanks for the suggestion. I found the issue, it seems the two API calls are not finishing before sending the information to the next screen. I was able to run debug from the browser and saw the issue.

Comment: Nice. If you still need help with this then please edit your post to include any new/relevant details and accompanying [mcve] to go with it.